# UML sequence diagrams for C++: what lifeline do functions of objects go on?

Tags: c++, uml

I need to develop a sequence diagram for some code, and I'm a little confused as to which lifeline a function that's called by an object runs on, in relation to the main() lifeline.

Here, I have a class called Results, with a function called Empty_Results, which resets a buffer of a separate database. It's defined in Results.h and Results.cpp which is #included in my main source file.

In main(), I create the object R of type Results using

```
Results R;
```

and then call the empty results function using

```
R.Empty_Results();
```

I'm really not sure whether this needs to be laid out like this:

[image]

Or some other way?

I'm a bit thrown as there's now an object of type Results in main(), so does the message actually leave main() in order to call Empty_Results? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you're missing the constructor and destructor calls from `main()`  to `Results` in your diagram.

Comment: for some reason the code doesn't seem to have a constructor for Results at all? It seems to run fine though

Comment: _"for some reason the code doesn't seem to have a constructor for Results at all?"_ Huh?? And what's this then: `Results R;`?

Comment: Sorry - I misread your comment. I don’t have any destructors in this so they won’t be included. The constructor Results R is there but will require a dashed line instead of a solid line, I understand?

Comment: Destructors are always called automatically, when the scope of a function is left.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few fixes:

[image]

The signature of the right life line is `R:Results` which tells that the name is `R` and its type is `Results`. Adding the bracket to `main` does not make sense. This is C heritage that it's a function. Actually its an anonymous object.  For simplicity it can be called `main`.

The first message is a creation message. Note that UML has strict rules about the appearance of any connectors it uses. The second just issues `Empty_Results()` and has no return value. Also here you only show the message with no prefixing whatsoever but with parentheses at the end.

Whether you need the `x` at the end for object destruction depends.